# How do I call a method in child User control when MainWindow Tab is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

How can I call method in UC from MainWindow? In my app I use MainWindow + UserControls + TabControl (one user control = one tabitem, as firefox).  I would call method in user control when I change tabitem. I'll explain this with an example.

UserControl code:

```
    MainWindow mw;
   public userControl(MainWindow main)
    {
        this.mw = main;
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

     public void LoadData()
    {
        using (var mod = new Data())
        {
            try
            {
                var query = (from c in mod.table
                             select c).ToList();
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = query;             
            }
            catch {}
        }
    }
```

MainWindow code:

```
    public void RefreshUserControl(string userControlName)
    {
        switch (userControlName)
        {//... others UC
          // ....
            case "userControl":
             userControl ue = new userControl(this);
             ue.LoadData();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void tabUC_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as TabControl;
        var selected = item.SelectedItem as TabItem;
        if (selected != null)
        {
            RefreshUserControl(selected.Name.ToString());              
        }
    }
```

Generally, example - When I change tabitem on "userControl" then refresh datagrid on this usercontrol. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Although I would suggest you to change your approach to create UCs here so that there is no dependency on MainWindow in UC but if you want to continue with it for now,

- you can have an Event in your Main window
- Raise that event when tab selection is changed
- listen to that event in UC as you have MainWindow reference
- do whatever you want to do in the event handler in UC